# How to put to the jquery object the value from the input on the change event?

Tags: jquery

In `$singleDesignWrapper`, there is an input. I need to retrieve the input value on change and put it in the content of `<p class="sidebar-design-name"></p>`

Something similar to what's done in the line:
 `$('.sidebar-design-number', $element).text('Design ' + (i+1));`

In general, the goal is as follows:
 there are nested design forms, and I need to dynamically populate values in the sidebar from the input located in `.field-name-field-design-name`. The input is not a direct child of the `.field-name-field-design-name`

Code:

```
    const $singleDesignWrapper = $(
      ".field--name-field-design .field--name-field-design-name"
    );

    $singleDesignWrapper.each(function(i) {

      console.log($(this));

      // Object where I need to put the value  
      const $element =
        $('<div class="sidebar-designs-wrapper">\n' +
        '  <div class="sidebar-single-design-container">\n' +
        '    <div class="sidebar-design-number-and-name">\n' +
        '      <p class="sidebar-design-number"></p>\n' +
        '      <p class="sidebar-design-name"></p>\n' +
        '    </div>\n' +
        '    <p class="sidebar-garments-locations-count"></p>\n' +
        '  </div>\n' +
        '</div>');

      $('.sidebar-design-number', $element).text('Design ' + (i+1));
      $sidebarDesignsWrapper.append($element);

    });
```

`console.log($(this));` shows four objects.
`console.log($(this).length);` is `=== 1`

Markup look like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  // some html here
  <div class="button-container current-step"></div>
  <div class="sidebar-designs-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-single-design-container">
      <div class="sidebar-design-number-and-name">
        <p class="sidebar-design-number"></p>
        <p class="sidebar-design-name"></p>
      </div>
      <p class="sidebar-garments-locations-count"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="field--name-field-design">
    <div class="field--name-field-design-name">
      <div class="js-form">
        <input type="text" value="hello">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field--name-field-design"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: *`console.log($(this));` shows four objects.* assuming you're using jquery, this will show *one* object a jquery collection.   More useful to you would be `console.log($(this).length);` which should `===1`

Comment: Can you add some relevant HTML and *context* (you mention a change event, but don't include it)?   Your code, as provided with extrapolated HTML, works fine (or at least, as expected with Design 1/Design 2 output): https://jsfiddle.net/c1v483ng/

Comment: `console.log($(this))` shouldn't show 4 objects. Each time through the loop it should just show 1 object. If it selects 4 elements, you'll see 1 object 4 times.

Comment: @freedomn-m Added HTML markup to the quetion.

Comment: Still works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbnsvfq3/   What is the exact issue you are having?  Is it getting the input's value?  Change `(i+1)` to `$(this).find("input").val()`  https://jsfiddle.net/Lbnsvfq3/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m 1. The content of the element `<p class="sidebar-design-name"></p>` should change instead of `<p class="sidebar-design-number"></p>` 2. In your example jsfiddle.net/Lbnsvfq3/1  it is initially set, but when the user enters something else in the input in `<p class="sidebar-design-number"></p>` the content does not change. And it should be changed on the fly

Comment: So your issue is that you don't know how to listen for the [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event?  (or, more specifically, use the `input` event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand exactly what you are trying to do but maybe this will help

```
const $singleDesignWrapper = $(
    ".field--name-field-design .field--name-field-design-name"
);
$singleDesignWrapper.each(function(i) {
    console.log($(this));
    // Object where I need to put the value  
    const $element =
        $('<div class="sidebar-designs-wrapper">\n' +
            '  <div class="sidebar-single-design-container">\n' +
            '    <div class="sidebar-design-number-and-name">\n' +
            '      <p class="sidebar-design-number"></p>\n' +
            '      <p class="sidebar-design-name"></p>\n' +
            '    </div>\n' +
            '    <p class="sidebar-garments-locations-count"></p>\n' +
            '  </div>\n' +
            '</div>');

    // $('.sidebar-design-number', $element).text('Design ' + (i+1));
    // $sidebarDesignsWrapper.append($element);
    $(this).append($element);
    const $input = $("input", this);
    const $element_to_update = $(".sidebar-design-name", $element);
    $input
        // ADD EVT LISTENERS
        .on("change input", function(evt) {
            // UPDATE ELEMENT TEXT VALUE
            $element_to_update.text($(this).val());
        })
        // SET INITIAL VALUE OF INPUT
        .val("Design " + (i + 1))
        // MANUALLY TRIGGER CHANGE EVENT
        .trigger("change");
});
```

Here's a [link to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcxre4fz/3/).